# Convert SQL query to Nhibernate Criteria

Tags: nhibernate, count, distinct, having

**My SQL query:**

```
select [CompanyId] 
from dbo.Bussiness_Company
where [BussinessId] in (11,12,13)
group by [CompanyId]
having COUNT(distinct [BussinessId])=3
```

**Explain:**
I have a table **Bussiness_Company** table :

**Bussiness_Company**

Id*

BussinessId

CompanyId

### **My data:**

Id---------BussinessId------------CompanyId

1----------10---------------------100

2----------11---------------------100

3----------12---------------------100

### Resaul query

CompanyId

100

- Thank for any hepl!

Sloved:

### This is my code:

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<BussinessCompany>();
 detachedCriteria.SetProjection(Projections.Property("Company"));
 detachedCriteria.SetProjection(Projections.GroupProperty("Company"));
 Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction();
 foreach (Bussiness bussiness in list)
 {
   disjunction.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Bussiness", bussiness ));
 }                  detachedCriteria.Add(disjunction).Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.CountDistinct<BussinessCompany>(m => m.Bussiness), list.Count));

 IList<Sonomi.Core.BusinessObjects.Bussiness> bussiness =
                    bussinessUnitManager.CreateCriteria().Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", detachedCriteria)).List
 <Sonomi.Core.BusinessObjects.BussinessUnit>();

 dgrCer.DataSource = bussiness;
 dgrCer.DataBind();
```

Comment: if you have a NH version 3.x you should be able to query that without a so complex code

Comment: I will try next project. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can try a such QueryOver code:

```
var bussinessIdCount = 3;
var bussinessIds = new[] { 11, 12, 13 };
Bussiness_Company bussinessCompany = null;
session.QueryOver(() => bussinessCompany)
  .WhereRestrictionOn(() => bussinessCompany.BussinessId).IsIn(bussinessIds)
  .Select(Projections.Group(Projections.Property(() => bussinessCompany.CompanyId)))
  .Where(Restrictions.Gt(Projections.CountDistinct(() => bussinessCompany.BussinessId), bussinessIdCount));
```